# jQuery .text not working, but .val does?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the code working in jsfiddle but when i implement the code into my solution it does not do anything.

When checkboxes are checked the idea is that it populates a comma seperated list of all items that have been checked into a div. However this does not work, but it works for a textarea fine?

http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/166/

This is the line in question:

```
 $('#standardFitFeatures').text(allVals)
```

Then I give the div then ID:

```
<div id="standardFitFeatures"></div>
```

This wont work at all, I have to create a textarea and change .text to to val

Any idea why and how I can sort this as I need it to populate the div?

Comment: If you give a working demo, what is your question?

Comment: Is the demo supposed to fail? It works just fine for me - what browser are you using?

Comment: @norfavrell - Read the first sentence =)

Comment: have you tried `html()` in your solution?

Comment: yeah the demo is fine, just when I apply the code to the solution it doesnt work, the bit where its .text. When I change it to .val it works. So my question is, why doesnt .text work or why wont the above code work in my solution?

Comment: not tried html() - how would i implement this - I am very new to jQuery

Answer (score 0):

put

```
$('#cblistp input').click(updateTextArea);
 updateTextArea();
```

and

```
 $('#cblistStatic input').click(updateTextAreaW);
 updateTextAreaW();
```

inside `$(document).ready()` if you want a consistent behavior

it is highly likely that you are binding events to elements that don't yet exist.

EDIT

`.val()` works for `TextArea` and `Input` whereas `.Text()` works for `DIV`... Please check if you are indeed using Div in the production code and not textarea.

Comment: Yes all that is fine. The code works in my solution when I add .val and use textarea, when I use .text to use a div nothing happens at all.